# Setting and getting global variable with Require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, global-variables

I'm using require.js and backbone.js. I'm trying to set a variable and then use it in multiple views throughout the app by calling the module containing the variable with `Require`. The module is:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var variable_a = "aaa", variable_b ="bbb" ;

    var some_variables = (function () {

        return {
            setVariableA: function (x) {
                variable_a = x;
            },
            return_a: variable_a,
            return_b: variable_b
        };

    })();

    return some_variables;
});
```

In my view, I include the module and then set the variable, then check it has been set:

```
someVariables.setVariableA('456');
console.log('someVariables.return_a is ');
console.log(someVariables.return_a);
```

But this returns `"aaa"` rather than `"456"`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common fact with javascript. when you separate scope, i.e., write something like

```
(function(){ ... })()
```

this child scope gets copy of everything from parent scope. Since you have primitive data types (e.g. `string`) in the parent scope, the child scope holds copy of the primitive data. So any changes you make in the child scope will not be reflected in the parent scope.

the work around would be changing primitive data to `object` so that child holds reference. For example

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var variables = {
    a : "aaa", 
    b : "bbb" 
};

var some_variables = (function () {

    return {
        setVariableA: function (x) {
            variables.a = x;
        },
        return_variables: variables
    };

})();

return some_variables;
});
```

and the call would be changed to

```
    some_variables.setVariableA('456');
console.log('someVariables.return_a is ');
console.log(some_variables.return_variables.a);
```

This will give you `456` as you expected.

Comment: thanks, this worked after adding "return some_variables;" to the bottom of the modelue. Can you add that in and i will mark as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 return_a: function() {
      return variable_a;
 },
 return_b: function() {
      return variable_b;
 }
```

instead of

```
return_a: variable_a,
return_b: variable_b
```

because **current** 'return_a' and 'return_b' **always** hold initial values of 'variable_a' and 'variable_b'

Comment: this didnt work. when I do it like that, the console.log returns the function definition rather than the variable